# How do I create this loop of sending large email and small email every 1min within a 5min interval

Tags: python, email

I am trying to formulate the logic for the following ....

```
1.  Send a large e-mail (1MB or so) every 1 min for 5mins. 
2.  Wait for 5 mins 
3.  Send 5 small e-mails (few 100 bytes) every 1 min for 5mins
4.  Then wait for 5 mins and start again 1 repeating the same cycle.
5.      Start with 1 again
```

I created an email script that can accept 1MB and few 100 bytes attachment,
my confusion is how do I create this loop of sending large email and small email every 1min within a 5min interval

```
import time

def email(attachment)
.......


while true:
    time.sleep(60) #Delay for 1 minute
    email(attachment)
```

Comment: You're going to want to learn about `while` and `time.sleep()`

Comment: @Jkdc - i updated with what I tried,above is going to send email for every 1 minute..how do I create this loop of sending large email and small email every 1min within a 5min interval

Comment: Make sure true is capitalized as `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to approach this.

The first is to use python completely.

```
def send_mail(large=True):
    """Send 5 emails, 1 minute apart."""
    for _ in range(5):
        # send an email here, large or small.
        if large:
            send_large_email()
        else:
            send_small_email()
        wait()  # 1 minute

def wait(mins=1):
    time.sleep(mins * 60)

def main():
    start = time.time()
    day = 24 * 60 * 60
    while time.time() - start < day:
         send_mail()
         wait(5)  # wait 5 minutes
         send_mail(large=False)
         wait(5)
```

That's the basic outline you'd use.

The alternative approach is to use cron.  Create two scripts, one to send a small email, and one to send a large email.  Set cron to run those scripts at the proper intervals.

Comment: wait(5) is waiting 5 mins or 5 secs?

Comment: 5 minutes.  Because the wait function multiplies by 60.

Comment: instead of while True,lets say I want to run it only for 24 hours instead of forever,how do I change it?

Comment: See my change for 24 hour run.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this in a lot of different ways, here is just one example. Hope it helps.

```
import time


def send_email(email):
    print 'sending %s' % email


def get_large_email():
    return 'large'


def get_small_email():
    return 'small'


def get_email(size):
    if size == 'large':
        email_to_send = get_large_email()
    elif size == 'small':
        email_to_send = get_small_email()
    return email_to_send

email_size = 'large'
while True:
    for i in range(5):
        email_to_send = get_email(email_size)
        send_email(email_to_send)
        time.sleep(60)
    email_size = 'small' if email_size == 'large' else 'large'
```